# JS: Should massive arrays only used by one function be created inside or out?

Tags: javascript

In a piece of code I'm reading there is a function roughly as follows:

```js
const toColor = (name) => {
  const colors = [
    colorHash,
    colorHash,
    colorHash // many more colors
  ];

  // some simple actions to get a color from the given name
  
  return color;
};
```

The `colors` array is quite massive and the function is being called a lot.
My understanding is that this array is therefore created anew every time the function is called. Is it good practice to move this array outside of the function and just have it persist there, or is the performance impact of recreating the array per function call insignificant?

Comment: _"...roughly as follows"_ - That _"roughly"_ can make a big difference, e.g. if that "roughly" hides a closure.

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to move it outside the function if it isn't written to.

Comment: @Andreas the function is a bit more complex than this but there are no further calls and no use of closures. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: This isn't valid JS, is it an array of objects or an array of strings with a `:` seperator?

Comment: @LoveDev you're right, I was thinking in TS.

Answer (score 0):

Any data that doesn't change per execution of the function should be stored outside of the function.

The same applies when talking about loops for the same reasons.

Comment: There's no loop, and this is a comment/opinion and not an answer.

Comment: A loop, a new closure, etc. the case still applies.